# Sinusoidal initial trajectory guess for DirectCollocation in Drake

Tags: drake

I am trying to provide the solver with an initial guess that is a sinusoidal trajectory. I was hoping that there would be a way to specify the initial guess for the individual knot points, because then it would have been quite simple to provide the solver with an initial trajectory guess for a trajectory of any shape.

I have only found examples using the `dircol.SetInitialTrajectory()` function, together with a PiecewisePolynomial with FirstOrderHold, i.e. a linear initial guess. Is there a way to provide i.e. a sinuosidal initial trajectory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetInitialTrajectory` takes an arbitrary `PiecewisePolynomial` as input, and will only be evaluated at the sample times of the initial guess.  So you should be able to pass in a `PiecewisePolynomial` that matches your sinusoid perfectly.

Alternatively, you can use the `SetInitialGuess` interface from `MathematicalProgram`, and simply iterate through the `dircol.state(i)` variables to set them (allow you to define the mapping to time yourself).

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for getting back to me! I did not realize until that you can use the inherited functions from ```MathematicalProgram```, but of course that makes a lot of sense. How would you go about creating a sine as a PiecewisePolynomial? Is the best way to use a series expansion of a sine, to use one of the "Coefficient-based construction methods" from the docs, or am I missing an easier route?